# Problema al añadir una class a un select con jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy generando un select con js en base a la seleccion de otro select,
aca el codigo de mi html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-3 form-group">
    <label>Tipo Institucion</label>
    <select class="select2 select2-hidden-accessible" name="SelTipoInst" id="SelTipoInst">
        <option disabled="" selected>Tipo Institucion</option>
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-3 form-group">
    <label>Nombre Institucion</label>
    <div id="inputinsti">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreinst" value="">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

si selecciono a debe reemplazar mi input "nombre institucion"  por un select 
pero al cambiar a select la clase del estilo se pierde, estoy usando la libreria "select2"
este es mi js

```
$('#SelTipoInst').change(function () {
    var inptinst = $('#nombreinst');
    var dininst = $('#inputinsti');
    if ($('#SelTipoInst').val() == 'Parroquia') {
        inptinst.remove();
        dininst.append('<select class="select2" id="SelParroquia" name="SelParroquia" ><option disabled selected>Parroquia</option></select>')
    }else{
        $('#SelParroquia').remove();
        dininst.append('<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombreinst" id="nombreinst" value="">')
    }
});
```

alguna idea de porque se pierde el estilo? gracias de ante mano

Comment: En donde inicializas los select2?

Answer (score 1):

Despues de que agregas el select, debes de inicializar el `select2` asi:

```js
$('#SelTipoInst').select2({
   placeholder: 'Tipo Institucion'
});
$('#SelTipoInst').change(function () {
    var inptinst = $('#nombreinst');
    var dininst = $('#inputinsti');
    if ($('#SelTipoInst').val() == 'Parroquia') {
        inptinst.remove();
        dininst.append('<select class="select2" id="SelParroquia" name="SelParroquia" ><option disabled selected>Parroquia</option></select>');
        $('#SelParroquia').select2({});
    }else{
        $('#SelParroquia').remove();
        dininst.append('<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombreinst" id="nombreinst" value="">')
    }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-3 form-group">
    <label>Tipo Institucion</label>
    <select class="select2" name="SelTipoInst" id="SelTipoInst">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Tipo Institucion</option>
        <option value="Parroquia">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-3 form-group">
    <label>Nombre Institucion</label>
    <div id="inputinsti">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreinst" value="">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```